# Using Airflow TaskGroup without setting direct dependencies?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

The "mainstream" way to use TG is
 `t1 >> t2 >> task_group >> t3 ...`

But in some cases, I'd like to use TG in a different way:

```
with DAG(...) as dag:
    t1 = DummyOperator(task_id="t1")
    t2 = DummyOperator(task_id="t2")
    t3 = DummyOperator(task_id="t3")
    t4 = DummyOperator(task_id="t4")

    with TaskGroup(group_id="myTG") as tg1:
        tg1 = DummyOperator(task_id="TG1")
        tg2 = DummyOperator(task_id="TG2")
        tg3 = DummyOperator(task_id="TG3")

        ##########################################################
        # setting direct dependencies on the "outer" DAG tasks: #
        ##########################################################
        tg1.set_upstream(t2)    
        tg2.set_upstream(t4)  

        # internal TG structure: 
        tg1 >> tg3
        tg2 >> tg3

    t1 >> t2
    t3 >> t4
```

As seen above, the TG is not chained directly to the DAG, but rather the internal tasks have dependencies on the "outer" tasks.

This actually works, and the outcome is as expected: (using Airflow 2.1.0)

[image]

However, this behavior is not documented anywhere and I couldn't find any evidence that this is supported by design. My fear is that this might be a side effect or undefined behavior, and might break in future releases.

Does anybody know if it's safe to use this method?

Comment: This is intended and safe to use.  You might consider submitting a PR to ask them to describe this behavior in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Airflow Task Group is a collection of tasks, which represents a part of the dag (sub dag), this collection has roots tasks (the tasks which don't have any upstream task in the same Task Group) and leaves tasks (the tasks which don't have any downstream task in the same Task group).

When you set an upstream for the Task Group, it just sets it as an upstream for all the roots tasks, and when you set a downstream task for the Task Group, it sets it as a downstream task for all the leaves tasks. ([method source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/dcdcf3a2b8054fa727efb4cd79d38d2c9c7e1bd5/airflow/utils/task_group.py#L276-L297))

Your code is completely safe, and you can also leave a task without any upstream, and add an upstream task for the second, which is not possible if you set the upstream directly for the Task Group.

You will not find any example in the doc similar to your code, because the main goal of the Task Group was replacing the Sub Dags, and set dependencies for the whole Task Group and use is as dependency for the other tasks/Task Groups, so your code is not recommended but 100% safe.